# 4 layer PCB controller below layer query

Tags: pcb-design, emc, controller

I have designed in 4 layer PCB.

- My Controller placed on the PCB top side / first layer.
- 2nd layer full ground plane.
- 3rd layer Power plane (fill or not? please confirm.)
- 4th layer ground fill.

Comment: It is really hard to understand what you are asking.  Can you re-phrase the question and maybe add a diagram of what you are talking about?  What do you mean by "controller"?

Comment: Does this help? http://www.hottconsultants.com/techtips/pcb-stack-up-2.html

Comment: A plane is filled by definition But you're wasting a 4-layer board if you aren't using that 4rth layer.

Answer (score 1):

I would check if it is possible to route the power traces on top side. Then, you can eliminate the third and fourth layer.
Might reduce the price by factor 2.